# How do I filter Nones out of a column of options?

Tags: scala, quill.io

I thought this would work to extract a List[String], but no. (anmKey is Option[String])

```
run(query[Anm].map(_.anmKey).flatMap(_))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the options, and the nones, use `flatten`

```
scala> List(Some("string1"), None, Some("string2")).flatten
val res0: List[String] = List(string1, string2)
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the options but remove the nones, you can use `filter`.

```
scala> List(Some("string1"), None, Some("string2")).filter(_.isDefined)
val res1: List[Option[String]] = List(Some(string1), Some(string2))
```

Comment: That's what I was hoping, but this is inside a Quill query which is a macro, and hence subject to bad voodoo.

Comment: @user3416742 if this answer solved your question then please mark it as "accepted".